# How to register vue components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have recently started using Vue and I was looking for getting to use [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) on my project. Due to framework and current setup in use I haven't been able to implement single-page-component .vue-files, and have instead simply written app & components with string-templates to .js -files.

I'm unable to figure out how to include draggable to my application.

Basic structure looks like follow:

```
#HTML
<div id="app">
 <mycomponent></mycomponent>
</div>

<script src="vuedraggable.js"></script>
<script src="component.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

--

```
#app.js  (simply a wrapper)
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

--

```
#component.js
    Vue.component('mycomponent',{
    template: `
        <form>
            <h2>{{ form.label }}</h2>
            <draggable v-model="form.fields" class="dragArea"> 
                <div v-for="field in form.fields">
                    <field :field="field"></field>
                </div>
            </draggable>
        </form>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: { ... form-structure-to-be ...}
        };
    },
    });
```

With this structure I'm getting error "vue.js:440 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom lement:  - did you register the component correctly?"

I haven't been able to figure out either "require" nor "import" method and assume that both require bootstrapping. Due to environment I'm working with I'm having hard time installing libraries with NPM & strapping, and I would prefer to register components manually - is this possible and how?

Could someone please give me directions ?

Comment: I think you should even include `sortable.js` library. Did you add it?

Comment: haven't added it, but I really guessed that it shouldn't be the reason custom-component isn't recognized... I could of course try it as well right now.

Comment: see the fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/b63zfwvt/ ). If you remove the script tag for sortable.js you get the error

Comment: You were right! Adding both sortable.js and direct reference to CDN vuedraggable resolved this issue - no additional configuration required. 

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.6.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.14.1/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>

... yet unable to understand why local vuedraggable.js didn't work, as it should be exactly the same file, but I'll investigate it.

Thank you - I really though it would require some additional registeration magic!

Comment: happy to know your problem is solved , :)